# AutoMapper ProjectTo with DbContext multi level Include()

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper, entity-framework-core-3.1

I need to perform multi level `Include()` query during EF Core select. I use AutoMapper with `ProjectTo<>()`.

I have specified in mappings `ExplicitExpansion()` which means navigation properties will not be populated automatically, because I want to have possibility to execute the same query multiple times and 
one time `Include()` navigation property but second time ignore it.

`ProjectTo<>()` method has params which allows me to include navigation properties into my select, but I need to perform multi level include. Is this possible? Such syntax like `Include(e => e.Collection.Select(sc => sc.MyProperty))` not working in this case.

I tried to use `Include().ThenInclude()` for `DbContext` and then perform `ProjectTo`, but in that case `ProjectTo` overrides my includes and they are ignored.

Now I'm not sure if that's possible at all to have `ProjectTo`, `ExplicitExpansion()` specified in mapping and have multi level include?

Comment: You don't need `Include`. http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#explicit-expansion

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu well... I need it, since AutoMapper supports include for one level inside ProjectTo method, why it does not support include for second level include.

Comment: Perhaps read more carefully the docs. Or check the relevant tests in the GitHub repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try?

```cs
dbContext.Entities.ProjectTo<EntityDto>(dest => dest.Collection.Select(item => item.MyProperty));
```

Comment: I tried, but that results in empty collection in result. Seems not valid expression.

Comment: It's EF Core 5 now, and this approach works

Answer (score 7):

> I tried to use Include().ThenInclude() for DbContext and then perform ProjectTo, **but in that case `ProjectTo` overrides my includes and they are ignored.**

This overriding is working as intended.

---

### `Select()` overrides `Include()`

This is explicitly mentioned in the [EF documentation](https://ef.readthedocs.io/en/staging/querying/related-data.html#ignored-includes):

> If you change the query so that it no longer returns instances of the entity type that the query began with, then the include operators are ignored.
>
> In the following example, the include operators are based on the `Blog`, but then the `Select` operator is used to change the query to return an anonymous type. In this case, the include operators have no effect.

**Include**

`Include()` instructs EF to load some related entities when fetching the requested result set. This behavior is added to the default loading behavior of EF:

```
var people = db.People.ToList();

var peopleWithPets = db.People.Include(person => person.Pets).ToList();
```

By adding the `Include()`, you've essentially expanded the loading behavior that happens under the hood when the collection is enumerated (in this case, `ToList()`).

**Select**

`Select()` **overrides** the default loading behavior with the new behavior you've defined.

```
var people = db.People.ToList();

var names = db.People.Select(person => person.Name).ToList();
```

When you call `Select()`, you essentially instruct EF to *not* perform its default loading behavior (which may or may not entail additional includes), and instead load *exactly* what you have specified (in this case, `person => person.Name`).

---

### `ProjectTo<>()` is a wrapper around `Select()`

You can think of `ProjectTo<TDestination>()` as a sort of `SelectFactory` which generates the appropriate `Select` statement based on the `TDestination` mapping that has been configured in Automapper.
Under the hood, EF still executes a `Select()`, and therefore the same behavior as described above applies when using `ProjectTo<>()`.

If you want to include additional related entities or any of their properties, you need to **expand the Automapper mapping**, as opposed to using `Include` on the query. If your mapping includes additional fields, Automapper will expand its underlying `Select()` accordingly.

Even if you had been able to include the related entities using `Include`, Automapper would ignore them anyway if you never defined them as a mapping.

Comment: I clearly understand that `This overriding is working as intended.` So, still, why AutoMapper intended to support include for fields with `ExplicitExpansion` but not supposed to support second level include.

Comment: @Alexey: You can include related entities using the appropriate mapping, but you cannot use `Include` to do so when you are also using `ProjectTo()` Explicit expansion entails that Automapper automatically tries to fill in _every_ property of the destination type, which might preclude the need for you to explicitly map the related entities (if the mapping can be done automatically, that is), but it still doesn't change the fact that you shouldn't be using `Include()` here.

Comment: what I'm puzzled about is that `ProjectTo` supports `membersToExpand` logic, but only one level.

Comment: @AlexeyKlipilin: Only one level sounds like an arbitrary rule, but it makes sense, as it specifically prevents **cyclic references** from becoming an infinite loop. If `Company` has `Company.Employees` and `Employee` has `Employee.Company` (i.e. the other side of that relationship), then you'd get stuck in an infinite loop of A instantiating B instantiating A instantiating B instantiating A ... Given the high likelihood of implementing Automapper's `ProjectTo` with EF and navigational properties, such cyclic references are almost unavoidable.

Comment: but AutoMapper easily handles cyclic references with usual `Include` approach.

Comment: @AlexeyKlipilin: `ProjectTo` write a specific select statement, generally no longer related to the actual entities but to some arbitrary DTOs. While EF neatly avoids duplicate entities for the same table entry, I'm unsure if it can guarantee the same thing across the board for custom DTOs, especially when you can nest a whole bunch of different mappings into one another. I'm not saying it won't work, I'm just not sure if it'd be a complete solution.

Comment: What about multilevel properties that are used in a method that is mapped in automapper? Example: Company.Address where Address have complex type properties to City, State and Country, then I get automapper to fill a "FullAddress" string that is the concatenation of the names containing City, State and Country. In this example (exactly the problem I got into), none of those properties are loaded by EF Core despite being used in automapper, so the FullAddress result is wrong.